# Get username used for IIS protected directory login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp-classic

Situation:
Multiple user accounts are created for access to a directory using IIS directory protection. Once a user successfully logs in, is it possible to obtain the username they used with ASP/VB/.NET/etc.?

Or is the only alternative for identifying users to use a separate database-backed system of accounts and credentials?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have disabled anonymous authentication `HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name` will return the domain and username of the logged in user.